# Can you filter on backreference fields?

Tags: keystonejs

If I have a relationship field on one model, say organizations to many contacts, can I filter from a field on organizations while in the admin UI list for contacts? I basically want to filter on the reverse relationship. I can see the relationships in the admin ui, but can't filter on them or display their data in the list view. Thx.

https://keystonejs.netlify.com/documentation/database/relationships/

Answer (score 0):

there is no such feature in v4. v5 is currently in alpha, hard to say if such feature land in release or not.